# Modify resource before save during PUT operation

Tags: rest, put

I could not find any specification or guidance for the following problem.
I have resource which representation is a collection of elements, or other words this is my contract, collection of same objects

```
{[
  {
     el: 1
  },
  {
     el: 2
  },
  {
     el: 1
  },
 ]
}
```

User doing PUT with collection containing duplicates, my business requirement is to delete all duplicates and save it. 
Resulting collection will contain only **el: 1, and el : 2**
Will it break existing REST pattern ? If so how would I do it in a REST-complaint way?

I also would lie to notify somehow client that duplicates were removed and modified resource available, however cant find legit response code

Comment: When you require to delete data, you call a `DELETE` method, not a `PUT` method. Also, if you ask for a "REST pattern" how about you tell us what your current `PUT` call looks like - or what you think it should look like - and then we try to help?

Comment: I don't really want to delete, I would like to clean up incoming data. Before save I need to remove duplicates.

Comment: If you ask for a RESTful approach, you possibly have to change what you want. If you want to stick to what you want, then you're not doing it the RESTful way. In other words: what you try to achieve appears not RESTful and your JSON response isn't following REST either assuming this is indeed the response of a single resource as you explained in your question. How about you ignore REST and just do it your way?

Comment: why its not REST? PUT is idempotent. My HTTP requests (example above)  will result in the same state on the server no matter how many times that same request is executed, right ? Only difference it will be clean up. Where  specification says incoming request MUST be equal to the STATE on a server?  My clean up always result in the same state on the server. Just question is how could I message it to user and I cant find anything in spec

Comment: A `PUT` doesn't delete resources, in your case redundant resources. A `PUT` either creates a resource under a specific ID *or* replaces an existing resource. It isn't supposed to check for any duplicates and remove data. That, by the way, isn't REST. That is how HTTP verbs are supposed to be used.

Comment: but i don't delete any resources. Question: lets say I have resource {'id': 5, 'name': 'test'} PUT and on a server I replace letter 't' with 'b' so I will save 'best'.. will it be REST? If no, why ? It is idempotent, and replaces resource.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165601/discussion-between-antohoho-and-quality-catalyst).

Answer (score 2):

RFC 7231 defines the [semantics of PUT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4)

> The PUT method requests that the state of the target resource be created or replaced with the state defined by the representation enclosed in the request message payload.
>
> An origin server SHOULD verify that the PUT representation is consistent with any constraints the server has for the target resource that cannot or will not be changed by the PUT.... When a PUT representation is inconsistent with the target resource, the origin server SHOULD either make them consistent, by transforming the representation or changing the resource configuration, or respond with an appropriate error message containing sufficient information to explain why the representation is unsuitable.

So taking the representation provided in the message body of the PUT request, and transforming that representation by stripping out the duplicates *is* allowed.

This shouldn't be a surprise - HTTP focuses on defining the semantics of the requests and responses; what the server actually does behind the scenes is an implementation detail.

> HTTP does not define exactly how a PUT method affects the state of an origin server beyond what can be expressed by the intent of the user agent request and the semantics of the origin server response.

There are, however, some constraints on the response if the server needs to change the representation of the resource

> An origin server MUST NOT send a validator header field (Section 7.2), such as an ETag or Last-Modified field, in a successful response to PUT unless the request's representation data was saved without any transformation applied to the body (i.e., the resource's new representation data is identical to the representation data received in the PUT request) and the validator field value reflects the new representation.  This requirement allows a user agent to know when the representation body it has in memory remains current as a result of the PUT, thus not in need of being retrieved again from the origin server, and that the new validator(s) received in the response can be used for future conditional requests in order to prevent accidental overwrites (Section 5.2).

... so you have to be a little bit careful with the metadata you return, so that generic clients know to ask for an updated representation.

> But what will be appropriate answer to the client? How client will know it has to retrieve new resource?

An HTTP response has [three parts](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3), the status-line, the optional header fields, and the message body.

The message body, in the case of a successful PUT response, will be a "a representation of the status of the action".  The information encoded into the response tends to be specific to the domain.  So it might be an HTML page that says "Success, we've updated the resource, here are some useful links."  Or it might be an HTML page that says "Success, we've update the resource -- but we had to make a few changes from what you sent us, here are some useful links."

So it's really easy for the end consumer to know what happened, they just read the answer.

The *interesting* question is: how do generic components know?  And the answer is that we take the information that we want to share with the generic components and express it in the language they understand: the semantics of the meta data in the status-line and headers as described by the specification.

The semantics of [PUT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4) require that cache entries be invalidated if a PUT to a resource is successful; so you get an eviction of the old representation for free.

But, if the server chooses to admit that it accepted the proposed representation without modification, then the server can indicate this to the generic components by including a validator header field.  That signals to the generic components that the message body from the *request* can be cached, and that the validator matches the representation from the message body (so the validator can be used on subsequent [conditional requests](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232).

Comment: amazing answer. Thanks a lot. But what will be appropriate answer to the client? How client will know it has to retrieve new resource? Still confused on that part